# SlidingMenu: "getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);" not taken

Tags: android, android-actionbar, target, slidingmenu, android-homebutton

**HomeButton is not Enabled to toggle the menu!**

it works in my *testing-app*, but not in the app I want.

Here the NavigationDrawerActivity:

```
public class NavigationDrawerActivity extends Activity{

    protected String[] drawerList;
    protected ListView drawerView;
    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    protected Context context;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context=this;

        drawerView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        //Android doesn't accept the ListView.setAdapter here..!?
        drawerList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer)).setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_list_item, drawerList));

        drawerView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent menu;
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
                    if(context.getClass().equals(ActivityMain.class)) {
                        Log.i("menu", "same Actvity");
                        break;
                    }
                    menu = new Intent(context, ActivityMain.class);
                    menu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(menu);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
                    break;
                default:
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
                    //new RalaAlertToast(context, "default");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) context, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionAPI14();
    }

    @TargetApi(14)
    private void actionAPI14() {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=14) {//disabled Target Check
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
        // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle your other action bar items...

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            if(! drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerView)) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
                return true;
            }else{
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerView)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I've read many forums and other sites about target...
but nothing helped.
What could be possible reasons?

I've also posted it for others, they are long searching for a simple way to make their own menu. Just extends this Claes. (I searched long, and in my *testing app* it works without any problems!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, that you call in your activity super.onOpionsItemSelected!